# Why Is My Iterator Not Iterating Over The List Correctly?

Tags: java

I am trying to learn about iterators and linked lists. So, as I typically do, I've been toying around with the code and I cannot figure out how the program is iterating over my list.

```
    LinkedList<String> matchedList = new LinkedList<>();        
    matchedList.addFirst("Cowabunga");
    ListIterator<String> iterator = matchedList.listIterator();
    iterator.add("Reee");
    iterator.add("Moo");
    System.out.println(matchedList);
    System.out.println(iterator.previous());
    System.out.println(iterator.previous());
```

As output I get:

```
[Reee, Moo, Cowabunga]
java.util.LinkedList$ListItr@15db9742
Moo
Reee
```

But I am confused. I thought that the cursor was initially between the items: "Cowabunga" and "Ree" where Cowabunga was the first element in the list. This, being due to it is when I linked the lists together. However as output, I get Moo and then Ree when I go to the previous twice. Why is this?

Comment: *I thought that the cursor was initially between the items: "Cowabunga" and "Ree" ...* No, not until you call `next()`. The cursor starts *before* the first element. Read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html has a nice diagram showing the cursor position. As you can see, the first position is before the first element.

Comment: To generalize and summarize rgettman's answer: don't change the length of an iterable object as you iterate over it--regardless of the programming language, exact data structure, or whether you're appending or removing elements. I just spent way more time than I care to admit trying to fix a bug in Python that was caused by me removing elements from a list as I iterated over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as an aside, you must have an extra print statement in your code where you printed your `ListIterator`, which would explain the output `java.util.LinkedList$ListItr@15db9742`.

Next, a `ListIterator` (and an `Iterator`) has its initial position *before* the first element, which is where [the `add` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E)) adds the element.

> Inserts the specified element into the list (optional operation). The element is inserted immediately before the element that would be returned by next(), if any, and after the element that would be returned by previous(), if any.
>
> The new element is inserted before the implicit cursor: a subsequent call to next would be unaffected, and a subsequent call to previous would return the new element.

So when you create your `ListIterator`, this is the state, with the "cursor" position of the iterator before the first element.

```
 list:  "Cowabunga"
 itr   ^
```

When you use the iterator to add elements, the position remains before the same element, even as more elements are added before the position:

```
 list:  "Reee" -> "Moo" -> "Cowabunga"
 itr                      ^
```

Then the `previous()` method returns the element before the position and advances it backwards.

```
 list:  "Reee" -> "Moo" -> "Cowabunga"
 itr             ^

 list:  "Reee" -> "Moo" -> "Cowabunga"
 itr   ^
```

Answer (score 0):

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E)

> Inserts the specified element into the list (optional operation). The
>   element is inserted immediately before the element that would be
>   returned by next(), if any, and after the element that would be
>   returned by previous(), if any. (If the list contains no elements, the
>   new element becomes the sole element on the list.) **The new element is
>   inserted before the implicit cursor: a subsequent call to next would
>   be unaffected, and a subsequent call to previous would return the new
>   element.** (This call increases by one the value that would be returned
>   by a call to nextIndex or previousIndex.)